# Determine if element in polars series is a specific set

Tags: python-polars

How can I check if each element in a polars series is a specific set? In pandas, it would be like this:

```
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series([{'a'}, {'a','b'}, {'c'}])
series == {'a'}
```

This returns the exact output I'm looking for (other than it's pandas). How do I do the same thing in polars?

Comment: I don't think you can as sets inside a Polars Series are essentially "unsupported". `pl.Series([{'a'}]).dtype # Object`

Comment: You can't have sets per se but there are set operations, at least in data frames. I'm not sure, off hand, if they're in the series API.